# How to disable a button in c# if a value is false

Tags: c#, debugging, button

I'm creating a clipboard editing program and I encountered an error when I use the Copy button. If the text box from where it copies to the clipboard's contents are null, then I get a "ArgumentNullException was not handled". I know this is because the TextBox it copies the text from is empty. I want to write a method where if the TextBox is empty, then the button is disabled. Here is the code for this button:

```
 // Copies the text in the text box to the clipboard.
    private void copyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textClipboard.Text);
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated. If I'm missing some more details please let me know so I can add them.

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textClipboard.Text)) may by this check help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initially set the button to be disabled.

Then you can use that code to detect the change in the text box:

```
    private void textClipboard_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyButton.Enabled = textClipboard.Text.Length > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for null:

```
 // Copies the text in the text box to the clipboard.
    private void private void textClipboard_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textClipboard.Text)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textClipboard.Text);

        }
        else
        {
          copyButton.Enabled = false; //Set to disabled
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't see how this would disable the button.

Comment: `Visible` might help you as well;

Comment: Maybe you should put this code at the ` LostFocus` event for textClipboard or `TextChanged` as @Szymon stated above.

Comment: @Tico, I don't think the OP wants the form (`this`) disabled; instead, I think he wants the button disabled _before_ it is clicked, not after.

Comment: @davidsbro That is exactly what I want.

Comment: As an edit has pointed out, `copyButton.Enabled == false` compares, not assigns. You might want to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You could initially set the button.enabled to false, and add a KeyUp event to your textbox:

```
    private void textClipboard_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        copyButton.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
    }
```